# jQuery/ajax POST an Array / objects to C# code behind

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

as i try to learn through other questions , still i cant get it to work

this is my code so far , trying to be as thorough as i could get .

**the event (on click)**

```
var resluts = []; //its a collections of id's - list items of unsorted list as strings 
$('#next').click(function() {
    var RLength = resluts.length;
    alert(resluts);
});​
```

**ajax POST**

```javascript
function UbpdateSecondStage(arr) {

    var WebMethod ="GetSecondStageData";
    var page ="Default.aspx/";
    var target = page + WebMethod;
    var SendParameters = Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.serialize(arr);
    jQueryAjxUpdt(target, SendParameters);

}


function jQueryAjxUpdt(targetUrl, SentPars) {
    $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: targetUrl,
              data: {
                     'sentobj':SentPars

              },
              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              dataType: "json",
              success: function (data) {
                                  //alert(data);
              }

   });
}
```

**C#**

```C#
  [WebMethod]
  public static string GetSecondStageData(object sentobj)
  {
      var x = sentobj;
    return ?? ...do i have to give a return.. even if i do not require one ?
  }
```

what is wrong with my code ?. it's first time i tried that approach .
thanks.

**I HAVE UPDATED FEW TIMES PLEASE READ IT AGAIN**

[image]

Comment: What is resluts ?

Comment: i put a break-point at the Code Behind , i just couldn't even get the debugger to get to that point (like it does not fire ) . so two options , my code is a not correct, 2nd option my VS or Windows has issues or some bug

Comment: I am also interested in the resluts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Modify your `WebMethod` like this and try again:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetSecondStageData(object sentobj)
{
    var x = sentobj;
    return DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

Comment: @LoneXcoder: As you have return type as string for the `GetSecondStageData` web method, you need to return a string.

Comment: still not working , i just want to ask , as it is now(look at the time of this comment) should it work ? othewise i will try solve O.S and VS 2010 problems , like delete solution files or move project ...etc' ....thanks

Comment: ok just modify the data part like this 
`data: "{ sentobj: " + SentPars + " }",`

Comment: ha! , thanks Alot Dude . i allmost wanted to thank god (: really it was such a pain , i disslike js in Visual studio cause my lack of knoelege and lack of debugging utils

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should have specified what you are passing ( sending to the server) and what response you are getting( if you are luck ;)) back from the server. If it's throwing or rasing any error then that should be specified as well.

Secondly there is no need to use the following code.

```
var WebMethod ="GetSecondStageData";
var page ="Default.aspx/";
var target = page + WebMethod;
var SendParameters = Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.serialize(arr);
```

you can work like this as well

```
var test=new Object();
test.myArray=arr;
jQueryAjxUpdt("<Relative path to the directory such as '../home/default.aspx' >", JSON.stringify(test))
```

again change ajaxFunction as follows

```
function jQueryAjxUpdt(targetUrl, SentPars) {
$.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: targetUrl,
          data: SentPars,
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
          success: function (data) {
                              //alert(data);
          }
    });
}
```

Haven't tested but I guess It will work let me know if don't. ;-) 
And finally I guess you haven't kept anything in your default.aspx page other then `@page` directive and It works even if you don't specify `[WebMethod]` attribute.

Comment: i will try , thanks, u could have  a look , now it's final update

Comment: My goodness I made a little mistake don't use $.parseJSON instead you should use JSON.stringify(test);

Comment: as it was solved with the help of @palash code in comment, and as he was the first to answer i chose to mark it as the correct answer . thanks alot for your help i will review your code again to learn some more. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code

JavaScript

```
function UbpdateSecondStage(arr) {
    var WebMethod ="GetSecondStageData";
    var page ="Default.aspx/";
    var target = page + WebMethod;
    var SendParameters =arr;
    jQueryAjxUpdt(target, SendParameters);

}

function jQueryAjxUpdt(targetUrl, SentPars) {
          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: targetUrl,
              data: '{"results": "' + SentPars + '"}',
              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              processData: false,
              dataType: "json",
              success: function(msg) {
              //alert(msg);
                 here your code
              },
              error: function(x, e) {
                  if (x.status == 500) {
                      alert("An error has occurred during processing your request.");
                  }
              }
          });
      }
```

C#

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetSecondStageData(object results)
{
    var x = results;
    return DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

Let me know result.